# Tensorflow issue for DDQN Cartpole problem

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I have done training for cartpole tensorflow model by following the article https://chuacheowhuan.github.io/DDQN/

While testing I followed the article https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc and
gave my x and y values as follows:

'''
x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/s:0')   ----> Initial state
y = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/a:0')   ----> Final action to be performed??

```
# We launch a Session
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
# Note: we don't nee to initialize/restore anything
# There is no Variables in this graph, only hardcoded constants 
y_out = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: x})
```

I have given x as the state of cartpole , and y the action on the cartpole, but it's throwing error as mentioned below:
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'prefix/a' with dtype int32 and shape [?]
[[{{node prefix/a}}]]

The tensors are:
prefix/r
prefix/s_next
prefix/done
prefix/model_s_next_Q_val
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/shape
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/min
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/max
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/sub
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/mul
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/weights/Initializer/random_uniform
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/weights
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/weights/Assign
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/weights/read
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/shape
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/min
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/max
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/sub
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/mul
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/biases/Initializer/random_uniform
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/biases
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/biases/Assign
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/biases/read
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/MatMul
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/BiasAdd
prefix/model_net/fully_connected/Relu
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/shape
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/min
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/max
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/sub
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/mul
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/weights
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/weights/Assign
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/weights/read
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/shape
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/min
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/max
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/sub
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/mul
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/biases/Initializer/random_uniform
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/biases
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/biases/Assign
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/biases/read
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/MatMul
prefix/model_net/fully_connected_1/BiasAdd
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/shape
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/min
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/max
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/sub
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/mul
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/weights/Initializer/random_uniform
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/weights
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/weights/Assign
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/weights/read
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/shape
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/min
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/max
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/sub
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/mul
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/biases/Initializer/random_uniform
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/biases
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/biases/Assign
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/biases/read
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/MatMul
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/BiasAdd
prefix/target_net/fully_connected/Relu
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/shape
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/min
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/max
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/sub
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/mul
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/weights
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/weights/Assign
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/weights/read
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/shape
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/min
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/max
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/sub
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/biases/Initializer/random_uniform/mul
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/biases/Initializer/random_uniform
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/biases
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/biases/Assign
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/biases/read
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/MatMul
prefix/target_net/fully_connected_1/BiasAdd
prefix/td_target/ArgMax/dimension
prefix/td_target/ArgMax
prefix/td_target/Shape
prefix/td_target/strided_slice/stack
prefix/td_target/strided_slice/stack_1
prefix/td_target/strided_slice/stack_2
prefix/td_target/strided_slice
prefix/td_target/range/start
prefix/td_target/range/delta
prefix/td_target/range
prefix/td_target/stack
prefix/td_target/GatherNd
prefix/td_target/Reshape/shape
prefix/td_target/Reshape
prefix/td_target/Cast
prefix/td_target/sub/x
prefix/td_target/sub
prefix/td_target/Mul/x
prefix/td_target/Mul
prefix/td_target/mul_1
prefix/td_target/add
prefix/td_target/StopGradient
prefix/predicted_Q_val/Shape
prefix/predicted_Q_val/strided_slice/stack
prefix/predicted_Q_val/strided_slice/stack_1
prefix/predicted_Q_val/strided_slice/stack_2
prefix/predicted_Q_val/strided_slice
prefix/predicted_Q_val/range/start
prefix/predicted_Q_val/range/delta
prefix/predicted_Q_val/range
prefix/predicted_Q_val/stack
prefix/predicted_Q_val/GatherNd
prefix/predicted_Q_val/Reshape/shape
prefix/predicted_Q_val/Reshape
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Sub
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Abs
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Minimum/y
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Minimum
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Sub_1
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Const
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Mul
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Mul_1
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Mul_2/x
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Mul_2
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Add
prefix/loss/huber_loss/assert_broadcastable/weights
prefix/loss/huber_loss/assert_broadcastable/weights/shape
prefix/loss/huber_loss/assert_broadcastable/weights/rank
prefix/loss/huber_loss/assert_broadcastable/values/shape
prefix/loss/huber_loss/assert_broadcastable/values/rank
prefix/loss/huber_loss/assert_broadcastable/static_scalar_check_success
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Cast/x
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Mul_3
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Const_1
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Sum
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/Equal/y
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/Equal
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/zeros_like
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/ones_like/Shape
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/ones_like/Const
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/ones_like
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/Select
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/broadcast_weights/assert_broadcastable/weights/shape
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/broadcast_weights/assert_broadcastable/weights/rank
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/broadcast_weights/assert_broadcastable/values/shape
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/broadcast_weights/assert_broadcastable/values/rank
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/broadcast_weights/assert_broadcastable/static_scalar_check_success
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/broadcast_weights/ones_like/Shape
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/broadcast_weights/ones_like/Const
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/broadcast_weights/ones_like
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/broadcast_weights
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present/Const
prefix/loss/huber_loss/num_present
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Const_2
prefix/loss/huber_loss/Sum_1
prefix/loss/huber_loss/value
prefix/optimizer/gradients/Shape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/grad_ys_0
prefix/optimizer/gradients/Fill
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/value_grad/Shape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/value_grad/Shape_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/value_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/value_grad/div_no_nan
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/value_grad/Sum
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/value_grad/Reshape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/value_grad/Neg
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/value_grad/div_no_nan_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/value_grad/div_no_nan_2
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/value_grad/mul
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/value_grad/Sum_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/value_grad/Reshape_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/value_grad/tuple/group_deps
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/value_grad/tuple/control_dependency
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/value_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Sum_1_grad/Reshape/shape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Sum_1_grad/Reshape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Sum_1_grad/Const
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Sum_1_grad/Tile
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Sum_grad/Reshape/shape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Sum_grad/Reshape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Sum_grad/Const
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Sum_grad/Tile
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_3_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs/s0
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_3_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs/s1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_3_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_3_grad/Mul
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_3_grad/Mul_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_3_grad/Sum/reduction_indices
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_3_grad/Sum
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_3_grad/Reshape/shape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_3_grad/Reshape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_3_grad/tuple/group_deps
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_3_grad/tuple/control_dependency
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_3_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Add_grad/tuple/group_deps
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Add_grad/tuple/control_dependency
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Add_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_1_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs/s0
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_1_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs/s1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_1_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_1_grad/Mul
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_1_grad/Sum/reduction_indices
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_1_grad/Sum
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_1_grad/Reshape/shape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_1_grad/Reshape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_1_grad/Mul_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_1_grad/tuple/group_deps
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_1_grad/tuple/control_dependency
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_1_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_2_grad/Mul
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_2_grad/Sum/reduction_indices
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_2_grad/Sum
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_2_grad/Reshape/shape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_2_grad/Reshape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_2_grad/Mul_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_2_grad/tuple/group_deps
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_2_grad/tuple/control_dependency
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_2_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_grad/Mul
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_grad/Mul_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_grad/tuple/group_deps
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Sub_1_grad/Neg
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Sub_1_grad/tuple/group_deps
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Sub_1_grad/tuple/control_dependency
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Sub_1_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/AddN
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Minimum_grad/Shape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Minimum_grad/Shape_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Minimum_grad/Shape_2
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Minimum_grad/zeros/Const
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Minimum_grad/zeros
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Minimum_grad/LessEqual
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Minimum_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Minimum_grad/Select
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Minimum_grad/Sum
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Minimum_grad/Reshape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Minimum_grad/Select_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Minimum_grad/Sum_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Minimum_grad/Reshape_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Minimum_grad/tuple/group_deps
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Minimum_grad/tuple/control_dependency
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Minimum_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/AddN_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Abs_grad/Sign
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Abs_grad/mul
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Sub_grad/Neg
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Sub_grad/tuple/group_deps
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Sub_grad/tuple/control_dependency
prefix/optimizer/gradients/loss/huber_loss/Sub_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/predicted_Q_val/Reshape_grad/Shape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/predicted_Q_val/Reshape_grad/Reshape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/predicted_Q_val/GatherNd_grad/Shape
prefix/optimizer/gradients/predicted_Q_val/GatherNd_grad/ScatterNd
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected_1/BiasAdd_grad/BiasAddGrad
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected_1/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/group_deps
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected_1/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/control_dependency
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected_1/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected_1/MatMul_grad/MatMul
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected_1/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected_1/MatMul_grad/tuple/group_deps
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected_1/MatMul_grad/tuple/control_dependency
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected_1/MatMul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected/Relu_grad/ReluGrad
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected/BiasAdd_grad/BiasAddGrad
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/group_deps
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/control_dependency
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected/MatMul_grad/MatMul
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected/MatMul_grad/tuple/group_deps
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected/MatMul_grad/tuple/control_dependency
prefix/optimizer/gradients/model_net/fully_connected/MatMul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1
prefix/optimizer/GradientDescent/learning_rate
prefix/optimizer/GradientDescent/update_model_net/fully_connected/weights/ApplyGradientDescent
prefix/optimizer/GradientDescent/update_model_net/fully_connected/biases/ApplyGradientDescent
prefix/optimizer/GradientDescent/update_model_net/fully_connected_1/weights/ApplyGradientDescent
prefix/optimizer/GradientDescent/update_model_net/fully_connected_1/biases/ApplyGradientDescent
prefix/optimizer/GradientDescent
prefix/hard_replace/Assign
prefix/hard_replace/Assign_1
prefix/hard_replace/Assign_2
prefix/hard_replace/Assign_3
prefix/soft_replace/mul/x
prefix/soft_replace/mul
prefix/soft_replace/mul_1/x
prefix/soft_replace/mul_1
prefix/soft_replace/add
prefix/soft_replace/Assign
prefix/soft_replace/mul_2/x
prefix/soft_replace/mul_2
prefix/soft_replace/mul_3/x
prefix/soft_replace/mul_3
prefix/soft_replace/add_1
prefix/soft_replace/Assign_1
prefix/soft_replace/mul_4/x
prefix/soft_replace/mul_4
prefix/soft_replace/mul_5/x
prefix/soft_replace/mul_5
prefix/soft_replace/add_2
prefix/soft_replace/Assign_2
prefix/soft_replace/mul_6/x
prefix/soft_replace/mul_6
prefix/soft_replace/mul_7/x
prefix/soft_replace/mul_7
prefix/soft_replace/add_3
prefix/soft_replace/Assign_3
prefix/init
prefix/Assign
prefix/Assign_1
prefix/Assign_2
prefix/Assign_3
prefix/save/filename/input
prefix/save/filename
prefix/save/Const
prefix/save/SaveV2/tensor_names
prefix/save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices
prefix/save/SaveV2
prefix/save/control_dependency
prefix/save/RestoreV2/tensor_names
prefix/save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices
prefix/save/RestoreV2
prefix/save/Assign
prefix/save/Assign_1
prefix/save/Assign_2
prefix/save/Assign_3
prefix/save/Assign_4
prefix/save/Assign_5
prefix/save/Assign_6
prefix/save/Assign_7
prefix/save/restore_all
'''

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way you define placeholder. You can refer to the relevant page:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/placeholder